# fabric3 : Intempestive Login for password when trying to run fab command

Tags: python, django, server, automated-tests, fabric

I am following the Obey the testing goat book and I try to automate some shell command server side using Fabric3

I have an issue concerning the`fab deploy:host=yyy@xxx`
`yyy` being username
`xxx` being folder name of my domain name

Whenever I run this command, I get `Login password for 'xxx':` and it just never seem to work even though I enter the correct one

Here is what I did so far:
1- did `ssh-keygen` locally and on the server
2- added on local side a file named `authorized_keys` which contains `id_rsa.pub` generated on server side
3- did the same operation on server side

Basically, both sides have a file named `authorized_keys`

**Local side (resp. server side) have `authorized_keys` which is just a copy of `id_rsa.pub` generated by the `ssh-keygen` command on server side (resp. local side)**

Could anyone review what I did so far and tell me if I **DID** understand the problem (or not), and what should I do to resolve this issue

Thank vm

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how I managed to make it work...

Basically, I deleted the old public key that I had linked to my user in my digitalocean droplet's settings, and generated a new one, on the local terminal using `ssh-keygen`, then I did the basic configuration by copying this public key server-side on following path `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ...

Now, it does still asks for my password, but does proceed to the execution of my `fabfile` script after correct password input

I'm thinking that the 'proper' way to setup a ssh with one's user is to do it manually through command-line ?

Anyway, problem 'solved'